# How to Get MRP, Product Order Quantity, Address line1, Address line 2 in Order Success page Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, order-success-page

I need to get

- Address Line 1
- Address Line 2
- Each Product Order Quantity
- MRP(Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price)

code inside

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml

```
<?php
$lid = $this->getOrderId();
echo  "Order ID:".$lid."<br/>";

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($lid);


$totall = $order->getGrandTotal();
echo "Order Total:".$totall."<br/>";

$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();

echo "Telephone No:".$shippingAddress->getTelephone()."<br/>"; 

echo "postcode".$shippingAddress->getPostcode()."<br/>"; 

echo "city".$shippingAddress->getCity()."<br/>"; 

$items = $order->getAllItems();


foreach($items as $i):
   $_productsku = 
$objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($i->getProductId())->getSku();
   $_productquantity = 
$objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($i->getProductId())->getQtyOrdered();
   $_productprice = 
$objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($i->getProductId())->getPrice();

echo "product sku:".$_productsku."<br/>";
echo "product quantity:".$_productname."<br/>";
echo "product Rate:".$_productprice."<br/>";
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Specify the problem which you face using above code.

Comment: no problems no errors. need to know, how can i get MRP, address1, address2, product order quantity for display purpose

Answer (score 0):

In your code in for each loop you are calling product obj for get qty order , it is not need just call from I object

Comment: ok how can i add it?